# Windows Authentication with DNN

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, windows-authentication

I have a local intranet facing DNN library portal site hosted in Windows Server. I have also configured Windows AD in the server and There's one more system connected to the server domain.

Basically, We have 2 tier access. 1 is Logging into DNN as Admin or Super User to manage the DNN and other one is, Logging into Portal as User to manage his account in the library. So, the former login process is handled by DNN itself and the later one handled by us using our DB validation.

Now, we are trying allow library users to login using Windows Authentication. For that, we enabled `Windows Authentication` and disabled `Anonymous Authentication`.

The problem is, When I launch the DNN I can login into Portal as `User` but NOT login into `DNN` as Admin. Even, accessing `IPAddress/Login` is just refreshing and stays on the Home page but not redirecting to `Login` page.

NOTE: I have already created `domain\windows user name` in the DNN admin user. but still I cannot login into the DNN as Admin.